# Maximum product of 13 adjacent numbers of a 1000-digit number

Tags: c

I have to find the largest product of 13 adjacent numbers of a 1000-digit number below. My code for the problem is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[1000] =
        "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450"
        "632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958"
        "331952853208805511125406987471585238630507156932909632952274430435"
        "576689664895044524452316173185640309871112172238311362229893423380"
        "308135336276614282806444486645238749303589072962904915604407723907"
        "138105158593079608667017242712188399879790879227492190169972088809"
        "377665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525849077116"
        "705560136048395864467063244157221553975369781797784617406495514929"
        "086256932197846862248283972241375657056057490261407972968652414535"
        "100474821663704844031998900088952434506585412275886668811642717147"
        "992444292823086346567481391912316282458617866458359124566529476545"
        "682848912883142607690042242190226710556263211111093705442175069416"
        "589604080719840385096245544436298123098787992724428490918884580156"
        "166097919133875499200524063689912560717606058861164671094050775410"
        "022569831552000559357297257163626956188267042825248360082325753042"
        "0752963450";

    int i, j;
    long int max;
    max = 0;
    long int s = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 988; i++) {
        int a = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
            printf("%c", arr[i + a]);
            s = s * arr[i + a];
            a++;
        }
        printf("%c%d", '=', s);
        printf("\n");
        if (s > max) {
            max = s;
        }
    }
    printf("\nMaximum product is %d", max);
    getchar();
}
```

Some outputs are zero even if none of the input is zero. The second output happens to be negative. The answers don't even match. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are zeros in your string. Why do you say that none of the input is 0?

Comment: looks like Project Euler problem 8

Comment: @phuclv Its definitely is

Comment: While you have bigger fish to fry, I wanna point out that if you want a fast solution, you don't need that inner loop to multiply 13 values.  You simply use an accumulator with a ring buffer to divide out the 13th-previous value and then multiply in the latest one.  Except when dealing with zeros -- whenever you encounter a zero you can basically advance 13 spaces.

Comment: @paddy I'm not acquainted with that accumulator ring buffer method ,would you please elaborate ?

Comment: Note: 9 to the 13th power exceeds 32-bit math.

Comment: It's just a common dynamic programming technique.  You have a 13-value array containing the last 13 values that you have processed, and you also have a single value containing the product of all those values.  When you add a new value to this array, you will be replacing the oldest value.  If you divide that out of your product, then the product is now only the most recent 12 values.  You then take the new one, multiply it into your product variable, and replace the oldest one in the array.  If you encounter a zero, you reset everything, as if you were filling from the beginning.

Comment: Here, I knocked up an example just for fun: https://ideone.com/MKdNnL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many set of 13 digits in your `char` array `arr` contains zeroes and that is why the multiplication of these sets will result in 0.

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- You are using `%d` instead of `%ld` to print `long int`. Using the wrong conversion specifier will result in undefined behaviour.

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.

- You are not converting the ASCII value of the digit into its actual value before multiplication. (ASCII value of '0' is 48). This results in **integer overflow** and is the cause for negative values to be printed.

So the statement:

```
s = s * arr[i + a];
```

should be changed to:

```
s = s * (arr[i + a] - '0');
```

- You are also not resetting the product `s` to 1 at the beginning of the inner `for` loop and because of this, you end up multiplying values from the results of different sets of 13.

After making these changes, you can see the live demo [here](http://tpcg.io/Ns5LXh).

Comment: I got it already though ...but how do I write it in the answer section ?

Comment: @NehalSamee: You mean the answer section here on SO?

Comment: No...In PE ...how do I write the two answers ...If I write in format 2×3×4 ...×0 I don't have enough spaces then .

Comment: @NehalSamee: I am not familiar with PE. But you only have to write answer that is working. No need for two answers.

Comment: Note, I followed the live demo link and found it did not match this answer.  I took the liberty of fixing it, and also corrected an off-by-one error in the outer loop, and made the inner loop more standard (zero-based indexing) even though for some reason there is a second variable used to count the offset.

Comment: @paddy: Thank you. I tried to make as minimal changes as possible to the OP's original code and therefore did not change the loop indexing, removing extra variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues to tackle in this code:

- Clean up spacing and variable names (an edit by another user helped resolve this issue). Remove redundant variables like `a`, which `j` could easily represent by iterating from 0 to 12 rather than 1 to 13. This seems cosmetic but will make it easier for you to understand your program state, so it's actually critical.
- Numerical overflow: As with all PE problems, you'll be dealing with extremely large numbers which may overflow the capacity of the `long int` datatype (2<sup>31</sup> - 1). Use `unsigned long long` to store your `max` and `s` (which I'd call `product`) variables. Print the result with `%llu`.
- Convert `char`s to `int`s: `arr[i+j] - '0';` so that you're multiplying the actual numbers the chars represent rather than their ASCII values (which are 48 higher).
- `s` (really `product`) is not reset on each iteration of the inner loop, so you're taking the product of the entire 1000-sized input (or trying to, until your `int`s start to overflow).